# How to access data source options (e.g. kafka)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am setting Spark batch process options to consume from Kafka , But When I try to get the config properties , it shows as None. why so ?

```
val df = sparkSession
        .read
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka.brokers".getConfigValue) 
        .option("subscribe", "kafka.devicelocationdatatopic".getConfigValue) 
        .option("startingOffsets", "kafka.startingOffsets".getConfigValue)
        .option("endingOffsets", "kafka.endingOffsets".getConfigValue)
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") // any failure regarding data loss in topic or else, not supposed to fail, it has to continue...
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "3")
        .load()

println("maxOffsetsPerTrigger "  + df.sparkSession.conf.getOption("maxOffsetsPerTrigger"))
```

Current output

```
None
```

Desired Output

```
maxOffsetsPerTrigger 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to get the config properties , it shows as None. why so ?

They're available to the underlying data source only. Spark SQL tries to hide the intricacies of working with different data sources and that's one of the many implementation details.

> df.sparkSession.conf.getOption("maxOffsetsPerTrigger")

That's different from the options you specify when describing the data source (e.g. kafka).

In the above you want to access a Spark property `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` and the `Option` part is about the Scala type returned not the common meaning of the word "option".

You can specify a Spark property using `--conf` on command-line. Note that only `spark.`-prefixed properties are allowed.

```
$ spark-shell \
    --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.4 \
    --conf spark.maxOffsetsPerTrigger=3

scala> spark.conf.getOption("spark.maxOffsetsPerTrigger")
res0: Option[String] = Some(3)
```

> Desired Output

Since it's not available out of the box you have to work it around and bypass some "private" fences.

The following code should do the trick. Use at your own risk.

```
// spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.4

val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "demo:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "demo")
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "3")
  .load

val plan = df.queryExecution.logical

scala> println(plan.numberedTreeString)
00 Relation[key#0,value#1,topic#2,partition#3,offset#4L,timestamp#5,timestampType#6] KafkaRelation(strategy=Subscribe[demo], start=EarliestOffsetRangeLimit, end=LatestOffsetRangeLimit)

// :paste -raw
// BEGIN
package org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010
object Util {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan
  def bypassPrivateKafka010(plan: LogicalPlan) = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation
    import org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaRelation
    plan.collect { case LogicalRelation(r: KafkaRelation, _, _, _) => r }
  }
}
// END

import org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.Util.bypassPrivateKafka010
import org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaRelation
val kafkaRelation = bypassPrivateKafka010(plan).head

// sourceOptions is a private field of KafkaRelation
// :paste -raw
// BEGIN
package org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010
object Util2 {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaRelation
  def bypassPrivate(r: KafkaRelation): Map[String, String] = {
    val clazz = classOf[KafkaRelation]
    val sourceOptions = clazz.getDeclaredField("sourceOptions")
    sourceOptions.setAccessible(true)
    sourceOptions.get(r).asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
  }
}
// END

import org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.Util2.bypassPrivate
val options = bypassPrivate(kafkaRelation)
scala> options.foreach(println)
(maxoffsetspertrigger,3)
(subscribe,demo)
(kafka.bootstrap.servers,demo:9092)
```

Comment: Hi jacek, as a workaround for the time being it worked. So, I am accepting this answer. Thank you for your help.